# NestJS validation property name not showing

Tags: node.js, nestjs, class-validator, class-transformer

In an NestJS Application I'm getting validation response this way.

```
{
    "statusCode": 422,
    "message": [
        "Uesrname is required",
        "First Name is required"
    ],
    "error": "Unprocessable Entity"
}
```

But I want to get the property / field name with each message.
I'm using ValidationPipe globally. Here is my config,

```
 app.useGlobalPipes(
    new ValidationPipe({
      errorHttpStatusCode: 422,
      forbidUnknownValues: true,
      transform: true,
      whitelist: true,
      validationError: {
        target: true,
        value: true,
      },
    }),
  );
```

Answer (score 1):

I just fixed this problem with this configuration

```
import { UnprocessableEntityException, ValidationError, ValidationPipe } from '@nestjs/common';

 app.useGlobalPipes(
    new ValidationPipe({
     // All the configuration Here

     // And add this line
     exceptionFactory(errors: ValidationError[]) {
        
        return new UnprocessableEntityException(errors);
      },
    }),
  );
```

Now the response is

```
{
    "statusCode": 422,
    "message": [
        {
            "target": {
                "username": "",
                "firstName": "",
                "lastName": "User",
                "email": "test9@test.com",
                "password": "test123"
            },
            "value": "",
            "property": "username",
            "children": [],
            "constraints": {
                "isNotEmpty": "Uesrname is required"
            }
        },
        {
            "target": {
                "username": "",
                "firstName": "",
                "lastName": "User",
                "email": "test9@test.com",
                "password": "test123"
            },
            "value": "",
            "property": "firstName",
            "children": [],
            "constraints": {
                "isNotEmpty": "First Name is required"
            }
        }
    ],
    "error": "Unprocessable Entity"
}
```